# This is an issue about the Knight Parade running timeout

Tags: c

When I built the project with the greedy algorithm and the backtracking algorithm, and then ran it, I found that there were some specific starting points that had a serious timeout during the run, which was not what I wanted, and I thought about it for a long time but didn't find the problem.
"stackbase.h" only includes some basic operations of the stack (initialization, Push, Pop), and you don't need to worry about it.

```
#ifndef _INIT_H_
#define _INIT_H_
#define MAP_SIZE 8
#define STACK_INIT_SIZE 70
#define STACKINCREMENT 5
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int num;                    //通道块在路径上的序号
    int x;                      //通道块横坐标
    int y;                      //通道块纵坐标
    int dir;                    //方向  direction
}Node;                          //栈的数据类型

typedef struct {
    Node* base;
    Node* top;
    int stacksize;
}stack;

#endif


#ifndef _STACKBASE_H_
#define _STACKBASE_H_
#include "init.h"

int InitStack(stack* thestack);
int Push(stack* thestack, Node elem);
int Pop(stack* thestack, Node* elem);

#endif


#include "stackbase.h"

int InitStack(stack* thestack)
{
    Node* p = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node) * STACK_INIT_SIZE);
    if (!p)
        return 0;
    thestack->base = p;
    thestack->top = thestack->base;
    thestack->stacksize = STACK_INIT_SIZE;
    return 1;
}

int Push(stack* thestack, Node elem)
{
    if (thestack->top - thestack->base >= thestack->stacksize)
    {
        Node* p = realloc(thestack->base, sizeof(Node) * (thestack->stacksize + STACKINCREMENT));
        if (!p)
            return 0;
        thestack->base = p;
        thestack->top = thestack->base + thestack->stacksize;
        thestack->stacksize += STACKINCREMENT;
    }
    *(thestack->top) = elem;
    (thestack->top)++;
    return 1;
}

int Pop(stack* thestack, Node* elem)
{
    if (thestack->base == thestack->top)
        return 0;
    *elem = *(thestack->top - 1);
    (thestack->top)--;
    return 1;
}


#include "stackbase.h"
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x, y;
    int board[MAP_SIZE][MAP_SIZE] = {0};
    printf("please input the initial x and y: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    while(x > MAP_SIZE - 1 || y > MAP_SIZE - 1 || x < 0 || y < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        printf("please input the initial x and y: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    }

    clock_t start_time, end_time; 
    start_time = clock();

    stack thestack;
    InitStack(&thestack);

    Node p;
    p.x = x, p.y = y, p.dir = 1, p.num = 1;
    Push(&thestack, p);
    board[p.y][p.x] = p.num;

    while(thestack.base != thestack.top)
    {
        switch ((thestack.top-1)->dir)
        {
        case 1:
            x = (thestack.top-1)->x;
            y = (thestack.top-1)->y;
            x += 1, y -= 2;
            if(x > MAP_SIZE - 1 || y > MAP_SIZE - 1 || x < 0 || y < 0 || board[y][x] != 0)
                ((thestack.top-1)->dir) +=1;
            else
            {
                p.x = x, p.y = y, p.dir = 1, p.num = (thestack.top-1)->num + 1;
                Push(&thestack, p);
                board[p.y][p.x] = p.num;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            x = (thestack.top-1)->x;
            y = (thestack.top-1)->y;
            x += 2, y -= 1;
            if(x > MAP_SIZE - 1 || y > MAP_SIZE - 1 || x < 0 || y < 0 || board[y][x] != 0)
                ((thestack.top-1)->dir)+=1;
            else
            {
                p.x = x, p.y = y, p.dir = 1, p.num = (thestack.top-1)->num + 1;
                Push(&thestack, p);
                board[p.y][p.x] = p.num;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            x = (thestack.top-1)->x;
            y = (thestack.top-1)->y;
            x += 2, y += 1;
            if(x > MAP_SIZE - 1 || y > MAP_SIZE - 1 || x < 0 || y < 0 || board[y][x] != 0)
                ((thestack.top-1)->dir) +=1;
            else
            {
                p.x = x, p.y = y, p.dir = 1, p.num = (thestack.top-1)->num + 1;
                Push(&thestack, p);
                board[p.y][p.x] = p.num;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            x = (thestack.top-1)->x;
            y = (thestack.top-1)->y;
            x += 1, y += 2;
            if(x > MAP_SIZE - 1 || y > MAP_SIZE - 1 || x < 0 || y < 0 || board[y][x] != 0)
                ((thestack.top-1)->dir)+=1;
            else
            {
                p.x = x, p.y = y, p.dir = 1, p.num = (thestack.top-1)->num + 1;
                Push(&thestack, p);
                board[p.y][p.x] = p.num;
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            x = (thestack.top-1)->x;
            y = (thestack.top-1)->y;
            x -= 1, y += 2;
            if(x > MAP_SIZE - 1 || y > MAP_SIZE - 1 || x < 0 || y < 0 || board[y][x] != 0)
                ((thestack.top-1)->dir) +=1;
            else
            {
                p.x = x, p.y = y, p.dir = 1, p.num = (thestack.top-1)->num + 1;
                Push(&thestack, p);
                board[p.y][p.x] = p.num;
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            x = (thestack.top-1)->x;
            y = (thestack.top-1)->y;
            x -= 2, y += 1;
            if(x > MAP_SIZE - 1 || y > MAP_SIZE - 1 || x < 0 || y < 0 || board[y][x] != 0)
                ((thestack.top-1)->dir)+=1;
            else
            {
                p.x = x, p.y = y, p.dir = 1, p.num = (thestack.top-1)->num + 1;
                Push(&thestack, p);
                board[p.y][p.x] = p.num;
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            x = (thestack.top-1)->x;
            y = (thestack.top-1)->y;
            x -= 2, y -= 1;
            if(x > MAP_SIZE - 1 || y > MAP_SIZE - 1 || x < 0 || y < 0 || board[y][x] != 0)
                ((thestack.top-1)->dir) +=1;
            else
            {
                p.x = x, p.y = y, p.dir = 1, p.num = (thestack.top-1)->num + 1;
                Push(&thestack, p);
                board[p.y][p.x] = p.num;
            }
            break;
        case 8:
            x = (thestack.top-1)->x;
            y = (thestack.top-1)->y;
            x -= 1, y -= 2;
            if(x > MAP_SIZE - 1 || y > MAP_SIZE - 1 || x < 0 || y < 0 || board[y][x] != 0)
                ((thestack.top-1)->dir) +=1;
            else
            {
                p.x = x, p.y = y, p.dir = 1, p.num = (thestack.top-1)->num + 1;
                Push(&thestack, p);
                board[p.y][p.x] = p.num;
            }
            break;
        default:
            Pop(&thestack, &p);
            board[p.y][p.x] = 0;
            ((thestack.top-1)->dir) += 1;
            break;
        }
        Node q = *(thestack.top-1);
        //printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",q.num, q.dir, q.x, q.y );
        if((thestack.top-1)->num == MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE)    break;
    }

    for(int i = 0;i < MAP_SIZE;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < MAP_SIZE;j++)
        {
            printf("%4d", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    end_time = clock();
    printf("SpendTime: %fs",1.0*(end_time - start_time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

It stands to reason that this code shouldn't run out of time, but it's not what I thought, and any suggestions you have will be appreciated

When I input 5 5, the project seems to be in an endless loop, which is not what I want, and I want to get a traversal board. I debugged for a long time and I didn't find any bug.

Comment: Where are stackbase.c/h? And [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You don't change `(thestack.top-1)->dir` in every branch so what prevents you from going through the loop in the same state?

Comment: Almost all of this code could be eliminated if you looked up the x,y offsets in an array indexed by dir.

Comment: I think that's a good idea. I'll try it. However, this doesn't seem to solve the timeout problem.

Comment: When `(thestack.top-1)->num` is big enough. It can go out through `if((thestack.top-1)->num == MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE) break;`